# What is a valid, efficient, and modern way to not load images on mobile?

Tags: performance, validation, mobile, semantics, responsive-images

I've come across this multiple times now and always solved it with a combination of CSS and JS, but with increasing support for responsive images, I've been searching for a more eloquent solution. I'm simply trying to *not* load an image on mobile, while retaining semantics (so no CSS `background-image`), taking advantage of browser pre-loading (so no JS lazy loading).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Use the `srcset` attribute with an image candidate string that has a URL of `about:blank` and a width descriptor of `1w` and set the `sizes` attribute's fallback `<source-size-value>` to `0vw`. Then, add CSS rules to hide the image for smaller viewports. Finally, wrap it in a `<picture>` with `<source>`s for absolute control.

---

## `srcset`

It appears to me that this can be solved using responsive images and a bit of CSS.

Consider the following responsive image:

```
<img
    src="foo-585.png"
    alt="foo"
    srcset="foo-375.png 375w, foo-585.png 585w"
    sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 585px, (min-width: 768px) 375px"
>
```

Despite there being no fallback `<source-size-value>` in `sizes`, `foo-375.png` is still loaded. So it appears we need to find an image candidate string that doesn't send any additional HTTP requests.

I searched SO for tips on how to essentially set a null image candidate string. I found several methods, all of which can be implemented like so:

```
<img
    src="foo-585.png"
    alt="foo"
    srcset="[URL] 1w foo-375.png 375w, foo-585.png 585w"
    sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 585px, (min-width: 768px) 375px, 0vw"
>
```

Note that a new image candidate string with a width descriptor of `1w` and a fallback `<source-size-value>` of `0vw` are added. In this example, `[URL]` is a placeholder for one of the URLs described below:

## Empty Fragment

[One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28077004/2103313) advises using an empty fragment (`#`) as a [valid](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/datatypes.html#common.data.uri.non-empty) option. Unfortunately, my tests indicate this method repeatedly sends HTTP requests to the current URL. Not good.

## Tiny Data URL

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14115340/2103313) recommends using [The Tiniest GIF Ever](http://probablyprogramming.com/2009/03/15/the-tiniest-gif-ever) in a Base64-encoded data URL:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=
```

Initially, I thought that at 58 bytes with very little opportunity for gzip compression on its own, it stands to reason that saving the GIF as an external resource with a shorter URL might be more efficient than multiple data URLs, but I was wrong; gzip eats multiple instances of this data URL for breakfast.

But, as [one comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775469/whats-the-valid-way-to-include-an-image-with-no-src/28077004#comment27308719_14115340) points out, data URLs are [slow on mobile](http://www.mobify.com/blog/data-uris-are-slow-on-mobile).

## No Scheme, No Host, Port `0`

[Yet another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5775621/2103313) suggests using a URL with no scheme, no host, and port `0` (`//:0`). This appears to work, but there are [concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775469/whats-the-valid-way-to-include-an-image-with-no-src/28077004#comment20144038_5775621) about firewall warnings. CSS is also required to hide the broken image styling.

## `about:blank`

That same commenter suggested using `about:blank`, which actually seems to work well enough, but like the last method, does require CSS to hide the broken image styling:

```
img {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    img {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

To me, this seems like the best option, as it is valid, efficient, and will not display any user-facing warnings. Those few lines of CSS seem well-worthwhile to me.

## `<picture>`

As the comments have pointed out, `srcset` isn't guaranteed. If the browser for some reason decides against your `about:blank` image candidate, then the solution falls apart. To remedy this, wrap your `<img>` in `<picture>` element and add the relevant `<source>`s:

```
<picture>
    <source
        media="(min-width: 768px)"
        srcset="[URL] 1w foo-375.png 375w, foo-585.png 585w"
    >
    <source srcset="about:blank">
    <img
        src="foo-585.png"
        alt="foo"
        srcset="[URL] 1w foo-375.png 375w, foo-585.png 585w"
        sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 585px, (min-width: 768px) 375px, 0vw"
    >
</picture>
```

Comment: You can not solve this with one `srcset`, you will need to use `picture`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574422/how-do-i-tell-srcset-attribute-to-load-no-images-when-viewport-smaller-than-cert

Comment: @alexanderfarkas While my method does not explicitly prohibit a browser from loading any source for a specific media query, it assumes the browser will select the `about:blank` candidate for that media query. Are you suggesting there are browsers which would not honor my combination of `srcset` and `sizes` (i.e. select a candidate other than `about:blank`)?